# confirmation message box in asp.net and re directions of pages

Tags: javascript, redirect, navigation, confirm

I have the following javascript code in my .aspx file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkValidation() {

        if (confirm("Data is not saved") == true) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";             
            }
        else {
            window.history.back(-1);               
            }
    }
</script>
```

when a button presses then the above method is called and everything work properly for external links!!!
However when I change the statement to

```
window.location.href = "~/Company.aspx";
```

or

```
window.location.href = '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Company.aspx") %>';
```

the link is not working. The links are not working if I try to navigate in my project. I tried several statements to redirect to another page in my folders using javascript. It is notable to say that sometimes the .aspx files are not located at the same level. For example I want to navigate for a child to a parent level.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
window.location.href = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Company.aspx") >';
```

Or this

```
window.location.href = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Company.aspx") >';
```

Hope this will help !!